# Cities $A$ and $B$ are $999$km apart. Road signs every km show distances to each city. How many signs use only two digits (without trial and error)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently, I came across a question that seemed as if it can only be solved using trial error. Here it is:

> There are two cities, $A$ and $B$, their distance is $999$km. Along a road that connects $A$ and $B$, there are road signs every kilometer. The road signs show the distance to both of the cities (distance to $A$, then the distance to $B$). Traveling from $A$ to $B$, the road signs would be as follows: $0|999$, $1|998$, $2|997$, $\ldots$.
>
> How many of these signs use only two different digits?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To solve this type of problem, a good tactic is to simplify it (instead of 999 km maybe 100 or something like that), find a generalized solution, and then apply your general solution to the problem. I'll give it a go and see what I come up with!

Comment: Actually, better to chose 99 for the smaller example. @BrianBlumberg

Comment: I assume you meant to write $2 \mid 997$.

Comment: The trick there is to notice that, if you have two (at most) $3$-digit numbers that add up to $999$, then their corresponding digits must add to $9$. (If $\overline{abc}+\overline{def}=999$, then $a+d=9, b+e=9, c+f=9$). Thus, you have already spent two digits on $c+f$ (since $9$ is odd, $c\ne f$) and all the rest of the digits must be either $c$ or $f$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you generally want to begin solving this kind of problem using a simplified version of it. Then you can progressively guess what the solution might look like. Eventually, you'll find a general solution that can be applied to solve the problem or any other similar problems.

For this particular problem, my first guess was to first look at all the numbers between $0$ and $99$. However, I did not plan on rigorously testing every single number. Instead, note that the set of $\Bbb Z$ between $0$ and $9$ don't satisfy your problem's condition, and any $9<\Bbb Z<100$ are of the form $nm$ such that $n,m \in\Bbb Z$. As per your question, $n \ne m$ and so the number of signs on one side of the lane which use only two different digits is $9*9=81$. Thus, going the other way we would find the same number of signs. Now, if for whatever reason both signs are merged into one (which makes no practical sense since cars go in different directions) then the problem solution would be a little bit different but you get the idea. You can take it from here using a similar logic and solve both scenarios where there are only one or two signs per kilometer.

Comment: "The road signs show the distance to both of the cities". (Maybe they're parallel to the road rather than facing one direction of traffic?)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that numbers that add up to 999 have a special property:  If we take a number that consists of 3 digits $a$, $b$ and $c$ (denoted $a{.}b{.}c$), then $$999-(a{.}b{.}c) = (9-a){.}(9-b){.}(9-c)\tag 1$$

Now $9-d\neq d$ if $d$ is a digit because $9$ is odd. This means that for each pair of signs, the set of digits that are occuring must have cardinality 2:

$$\#\{a,b,c,9-a,9-b,9-c\}= 2$$

That set consists of some digit $d$ and its complement $9-d$,
which means we may pick any number $a{.}b{.}c$ that is comprised of 1 digit or of 2 complementary digits.

There are 10 3-digit numbers made of 1 digit.  And there are $3\cdot 10$ numbers made of 2 complementary digits (including leading 0's which must be accounted for). Adding up, we get 40 pairs of signs using 2 digits only.

---

As an aside, similar to $(1)$ applies to all $k$-digit numbers in base $b$ when subtracted from $b^k-1$.